# ReflectedType from MemberExpression

Tags: c#, .net, linq-expressions

Given this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Expression<Func<SomeDerivedClass, object>> test = i => i.Prop;
    var body = (UnaryExpression) test.Body;
    Console.WriteLine(((MemberExpression) body.Operand).Member.ReflectedType);
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public int Prop { get; private set; }
}

public class SomeDerivedClass : SomeClass
{
}
```

I would have expected ReflectedType to be SomeDerivedClass given that it is the type of the parameter for the expression. But it is SomeClass, which is - if i understand correctly - the declaring type.

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The precise details of how expression trees get built are largely unspecified. The only thing that matters is that the expression tree corresponds to the C# syntax used to build the expression tree. In an ordinary C# expression, there is only the equivalent of `DeclaringType`, which gets encoded in the IL. The member isn't accessed through reflection at all, so there is no `ReflectedType` to consider. Because there is no `ReflectedType` to consider, the two different `PropertyInfo` objects corresponds equally well to the original source code.

For a potential reason why, consider this somewhat evil derived class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDerivedClass : SomeClass
{
    public int get_Prop() { return 4; }
}
```

Here, the base class's `Prop` getter is *not* overridden, *but* the original `get_Prop` property compiler-generated getter function is only available through the base class. Therefore, the only correct property getter for `Prop` is `SomeClass.get_Prop`. `SomeDerivedClass.get_Prop` *must not* be used, even if `Prop` is accessed on an object statically known to be a `SomeDerivedClass`.

Combine this with the fact that internally, the C# compiler-generated code to build the expression tree obtains the appropriate `PropertyInfo` objects by getting the property getter methods, and asking the runtime to find the corresponding `PropertyInfo`, and you have your answer: the property getter method can only reliably be obtained from `SomeClass`, therefore you will also get the `PropertyInfo` from `SomeClass`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I've misunderstood the question. Just ran the code and those are indeed the same

Comment: You can illustrate this with a `virtual` base property too. With `override` keyword, you get `SomeClass`. However, with (ugly) `new` keyword, you get `SomeDerivedClass`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the expression evaluates to `Prop` which is defined in `SomeClass` and not in  `SomeDerivedClass`. Notice that `SomeDerivedClass` is merely the type of your `test` lambda parameter, so it has nothing to do with the type of its body, which is an `UnaryExpression` accessing a property located in `SomeClass`.

Try also adding `Prop` to `SomeDerivedClass`, and you'll get your expected result.

Comment: Will not work if the base property is `virtual` and you `override` it.

Answer (score -1):

The `ReflectedType` property retrieves the Type object that was used to obtain this instance of `MemberInfo`. This may differ from the value of the `DeclaringType` property if this MemberInfo object represents a member that is inherited from a base class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype.aspx

Comment: You've misunderstood the question. OP says `ReflectedType` is the base type whereas he'd expect it to be the descendant class type, and I've explained why, based on the documentation reflected type is the one declaring the member

Comment: `DeclaringType` is always the one declaring the member, that's why it's called `DeclaringType`. In the OP's case, `DeclaringType` and `ReflectedType` will *both* be `SomeClass`.